# Can't connect to desktop via ssh

Tags: 10.10, remote-access, openssh

Trying to setup a remote ssh file server (sftp)

I've done it before but for some reason with ubuntu 10.10
I cannot connect to the assigned ssh port.

I setup the sshd_config file to listen on a specific port that didn't work
so i changed back to the default :22

then I reinstalled because I couldn't get my samba shares to work either..

so from scratch I changed the port again and I didn't setup a private key file
I just tried to connect via ssh over the local network

> ssh Username@192.168.2.1:22
>   ssh: Could not resolve hostname 192.168.2.1:22: Name or service not known

every time no matter what I do I get that message 
if it's the wrong port it just says Connection refused 
is there some weird ip rule that is setup in Mav Meerkat? 
 I've done this plenty of times 
and have been using Linux since Ubuntu 8.10 so I am not new to this
Please Help!!

Answer (score 7):

ssh doesn't understand this *address:port* syntax.

Use just `ssh Username@192.168.2.1` if you use the standard port or 
`ssh -p 1234 Username@192.168.2.1` if you want to connect to port *1234*

Comment: Yeah and this is the result ssh -p 1234 username@192.168.2.1
Connection closed by 192.168.2.1   any ideas?

Comment: The program on that port doesn't want to talk to your ssh client. Maybe it's not a ssh server.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out.. Like an idiot I removed the Host key files.. works like a champ now.. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my Host key files ***etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key*** ***etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key*** on both my client and host machines somehow. so openssh server wouldn't allow any connections. reinstalled and it worked. but as florian said I was using the incorrect ***address:port syntax also.***